# Cover a 15×8 board with the pentominoes

Tags: tiling, polyomino

1. Cover the entire area of the 15×8 square shape with two complete sets of 12 different types of pentominoes.
2. The pentominos can be rotated and flipped.
3. Two pentominoes of the same type must not be adjacent to each other even by a corner.
4. The edges of some pentominoes are already specified.

[image]

Comment: Did you make this puzzle yourself?

Comment: No. I found this puzzle in one PC magazine from 2013. I did not find solution. So I posted this puzzle here.

Comment: What is the name of that PC Magazine... or is it really [_PC Magazine_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCMag)?